# Não está sendo possível converter int em string C#

Tags: c#

Eu criei esse GET de leitura do banco, mas quando eu leio o id, ele da o seguinte erro "Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo 'int' em 'string'", ele está me dizendo que led.id precisa ser obrigatoriamente string?

é como se o led.id fosse uma string que não da para converter.

```
public static List<Led> GetStatus()
        {
            List<Led> lista = new List<Led>();
            try
            {
                NpgsqlConnection conexao = Conexao.GetConexao();
                string sql = "select * from led";
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conexao);
                NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    int id = (int)dr["id"];
                    string status = (string)dr["status"];
                    Led led = new Led();
                    led.id = id;
                    led.status = status;
                    lista.Add(led);
                }
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException erro)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Erro de sql. " + erro.Message);
            }
            return lista;
        }
```

Comment: Primeiro tu olha o valor que está vindo em `dr["id"]` e se for realmente um inteiro, tente utilizar outra forma de conversão: `Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"])`. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ele diz que não pode converter object em int, se eu coloco assim int id = dr["id"]; e se está assim Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]); ele ainda da o mesmo erro, o código do erro é CS0029.

Comment: Então na sua variável `dr["id"]` não está vindo uma string de inteiro e sim um objeto, verifique o seu DataReader pra ver se está retornando os valores como o esperado.

Comment: Como é sua tabela `led`? Poderia descreve-la e também passar pelo menos uma linha de dados que armazena nela como exemplo?

Comment: tabela led tem só um id - bigserial e status - charactere varying em postgres, tem um dado id 1 e status 1 se eu tirar o id e deixar para mostrar no get só o status funciona do jeito que o status está só que com id não está funcionando dessa forma ali.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
public static List<Led> GetStatus()
{
    try
    {
        using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Conexao.GetConexao()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "select * from led";
            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]);
                        string status = (string)dr["status"];
                        Led led = new Led();
                        led.id = id;
                        led.status = status;
                        lista.Add(led);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NpgsqlException erro)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Erro de sql. " + erro.Message);
    }

    return lista;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado